# Why doesn't this code return json data?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to fetch data from database using Node.js and MySQL.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
var app=require('express')();
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var mysql=require('mysql');
var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end();
}).listen(8081);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "",
    database: 'books'
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");
    } else if ( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/book', function(req, res){
    var data={
        'error': 1,
        'Books': ""
    };
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM book", function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length!=0){
            data['error']=0;
            data['Books']=rows;
            res.json(data);
        }else{
            data['Books']='No books found';
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I execute `node server.js` it shows following output in the cmd:

**Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Connected to MySQL**

But when I visit to http://127.0.0.1:8081/book, it doesn't display any output.

NOTE: My XAMPP Apache server and MySQL are started.

Comment: Try reducing it to just `app.get('/book', function(req, res) { res.json({ Books: 'No books found' }) })` and see if that works to make sure `app.get` is working like you think it should. Also check your error log, it's possible there was an exception from the SQL query, like if there's no `book` table.

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Is it okay that I've written server code in this JS file and at the same time Apache server is on? Secondly, I've written nothing inside `response.end()` Is it okay?

Comment: Dunno. Depends on how Apache is configured whether it will reload changed Javascript files. Couldn't hurt to restart Apache. Just offering basic debugging advice: strip it down and build it back up from there.

Comment: No, I reduced it and still there's no response.

Comment: @Schwern it's working when I replaced the createServer code and simply wrote `app.listen(8081)` in the end. Why is it so? Any idea?

Comment: I don't know this framework, but it seems like the `http` stuff and the `app` stuff have no relationship to each other and are possibly redundant. I think before you were talking to `http` which just wrote a header. Now you're talking to `app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, I believe, that you're using two different and redundant web servers. One is `http` and the other is `app` (ie. [Express](https://expressjs.com)). Only `http` is actually listening on port 8081.

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end();
}).listen(8081);
```

Since all it ever does is write a `text/plain` header and exit you'll get a blank page no matter what path you try to access.

The other one, `app`, never listens on a port. So all that `app` code sets up a server that can't be accessed.

So remove all the `http` stuff, you don't need it. Express handles this for you. Then call `app.listen(8081)`.

```
var app        = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "",
    database: 'books'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");
    } else if ( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/book', function(req, res){
    var data={
        'error': 1,
        'Books': ""
    };
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM book", function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length!=0){
            data['error']=0;
            data['Books']=rows;
            res.json(data);
        }else{
            data['Books']='No books found';
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port 8081');
});
```